# Can a JavaFX application self-upgrade?

Tags: windows, javafx, wix, windows-installer

I developed a JavaFX application and singe I'm using Gradle to build my project I'm using the [JavaFX-Gradle-Plugin](https://github.com/FibreFoX/javafx-gradle-plugin) to build native versions of my application.

Creating the `.exe` and `.msi` installers is working but I'm having trouble finding how is the application supposed to self-upgrade. Is this possible at all? Does Wix provide a solution for this? It seems like it does from some of the configuration parameters but that's just the tip of the iceberg when it comes to self-upgrades, signatures, etc.